# Не запускается команда npm run watch

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm

Не запускается команда `npm run watch`. Версия ноды `v18.12.1` версия `npm 8.19.2`

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "watch"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Goshka\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-24T11_01_43_629Z-debug-0.log
```

Лог:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.19.2
2 info using node@v18.12.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 5ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 22ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 25ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 5ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\xampp\htdocs\proj2\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 6ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Goshka\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Goshka\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 3ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 4ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 54ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 55ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 4ms
21 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
22 verbose title npm run watch
23 verbose argv "run" "watch"
24 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 6ms
25 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 14ms
26 timing npm:load:display Completed in 21ms
27 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Goshka\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
28 verbose logfile C:\Users\Goshka\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-24T11_01_43_629Z-debug-0.log
29 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 22ms
30 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 1ms
31 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
32 timing npm:load Completed in 115ms
33 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
34 silly logfile done cleaning log files
35 timing command:run Completed in 22ms
36 verbose stack Error: Missing script: "watch"
36 verbose stack
36 verbose stack To see a list of scripts, run:
36 verbose stack   npm run
36 verbose stack     at RunScript.run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\run-script.js:98:13)
36 verbose stack     at async module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js:78:5)
37 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\proj2
38 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
39 verbose node v18.12.1
40 verbose npm  v8.19.2
41 error Missing script: "watch"
41 error
41 error To see a list of scripts, run:
41 error   npm run
42 verbose exit 1
43 timing npm Completed in 199ms
44 verbose code 1
45 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
45 error     C:\Users\Goshka\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-24T11_01_43_629Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: В ваше package.json такая команда прописана?

Comment: если ларавель 9 то такой команды больше нет, так как теперь там не используется webpack а используется vite читайте документацию. И все скрипты которые можете запустить прописаны в package.json